# $\triangle ABC$ is an equilateral triangle with circumcentre $O(1,2)$ and vertex $A$ lying on the line $5x+2y=4$.Find area of quadrilateral $BCDE$.

Tags: geometry, triangles, analytic-geometry, circles

$\triangle ABC$ is an equilateral triangle with circumcentre $O(1,2)$ and vertex $A$ lying on the line $5x+2y=4$. A circle with
centre $I(2,0)$ passes through the vertices $B$ and $C$ and intersects the sides $AC$ and $AB$ at $D$ and $E$ respectively. Find area of quadrilateral $BCDE$.

**My Attempt**

All I could do here was finding the perpendicular distance of $O$ from the given line. How do I use $I(2,0)$

Comment: This hurts my head to even think about...

Comment: Hint: A, O, and I are all the same distance from B and C.  What does that say about those three points?

Comment: So you mean to say that $A,O,I$ are collinear

Comment: $A,O,I$ are collinear so we can easily find the coordinate of $A$.

Comment: $A\equiv (-4,12)$

Comment: What about $D$ and $E$

Comment: You know $A$, so you know the radius of the circumcircle, and thus the entire circle. There are only two points on that circle that form an equilateral triangle with $A$. Call one $B$, the other $C$ (which is which does not matter). Now you know the radius of the other circle and the two sides $\overline{AB}, \overline{AC}$, and thus can find $D$ and $E$ and the area.

Comment: Is there a geometrical solution to finding length DE

Comment: Hi @PaulSinclair, from the equation of circumcircle, how can we find B and C?

Comment: @aarbee - As an equilateral triangle with circumcenter $O$, $AB = \sqrt 3 AO$. The circle about A of radius $\sqrt 3 AO$ intersects the circumcircle in $B$ and $C$. For a geometric construction, construct an equilateral triangle on $\overline{AO}$ with third vertex $F$. Bisect $\overline{FO}$ at $G$. $B$ is the intersection of the line through $A$ and $G$ with the circumcircle. Again, the circles of radius $AB$ about either $A$ or $B$ intersect each other, and the circumcircle, in $C$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

As can be seen in figure OI is coincident on altitude of AH. The equation of AH is:

$y-2=\frac{-2}{2-1}(x-1)\Rightarrow y=-2x+4$

This with line $2y+5x=4$ gives $A(-4, 12)$ and we hav:

$AO=\sqrt {(1+4)^2+(12-2)^2}\approx 11.2$

$OH=\frac{AO}2=5.6$

$AH=\frac{3\times AO}2=16.8$

$AC=\frac{AH}{\sin 60}\approx 19.4$

$A_{ABC}=\frac{19.4\times 16.8}2=163$

$OI=\sqrt{1^2+5^2}=\sqrt 5\approx 2.24$

Now :

$IH=OH-OI=5.6-2.24=3.36$

$R=IC=\sqrt {3.36^2+(\frac{19.4}2)^2}\approx 10$

Equation of circle is:

$(x-2)^2+y^2=10^2$

This with line AH , $y=-2x+4$ gives:

$p(1-\sqrt 5, 2+2\sqrt 5$ and $Q(1+\sqrt 5, 2-2\sqrt 5)$

$AP=\sqrt{(-4-1+\sqrt 5)^2+(12-2-2\sqrt 5}\approx 6.2$

$ED=\frac{6.2}{16.8}\times 19.4\approx 7\Rightarrow A_{AED}=\frac 12(7\times 6.2)\approx 22$

$A_{BCDE}\approx 163-22=141$
.

Comment: The ratio of $AP$ to $AH$ is not the same as the ratio of $ED$ to $AC$. If $P$ lay on the chord $\overline{ED}$, it would be. But $P$ is the intersection of $\overline{AH}$ with the circle, not the chord.

Answer (score 3):

I think that we don't have to find the coordinates of the points except $A$.

We have $A(-4,12),OA=5\sqrt 5$ and $AI=6\sqrt 5$.

Let $H$ be the midpoint of $BC$.

Then, since $OA=OC$ and $\angle{HOC}=60^\circ$, we have
$$AC=2CH=2\times \frac{\sqrt 3}{2}OC=2\times\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}OA=5\sqrt{15}$$

Next, let $L$ be the midpoint of $CD$ where $IL\perp CD$.

Then, we have
$$\begin{align}AD&=AC-CD
\\\\&=2CH-2CL
\\\\&=\sqrt 3\ OA-2\sqrt{CI^2-IL^2}
\\\\&=\sqrt 3\ OA-2\sqrt{CH^2+HI^2-\bigg(\frac{AI}{2}\bigg)^2}
\\\\&=\sqrt 3\ OA-2\sqrt{\bigg(\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}OA\bigg)^2+(AH-AI)^2-\bigg(\frac{AI}{2}\bigg)^2}
\\\\&=\sqrt 3\ OA-2\sqrt{\bigg(\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}OA\bigg)^2+\bigg(\frac{3}{2}OA-AI\bigg)^2-\bigg(\frac{AI}{2}\bigg)^2}
\\\\&=\sqrt{15}\end{align}$$

So, the answer is
$$\frac{\sqrt 3}{4}(AC^2-AD^2)=\color{red}{90\sqrt 3}$$

Comment: I found same $90\sqrt 3$... Not %100 sure.

Comment: Hi. How do we conclude that DE is parallel to BC?

Comment: @aarbee : Since the quadrilateral $BCDE$ is cyclic, its opposite angles are [supplementary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_quadrilateral#Supplementary_angles). So, $\angle{ADE}=\angle{EBC}=\angle{ACB}$ which implies that $DE$ is parallel to $BC$.

Comment: Thanks, got it.